# Will the community please undelete my answer to this question

Tags: discussion, status-norepro, deleted-answers

There is nothing in my answer to this question (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81599/7303) that would fall into the category of deletion. I am asking for the community to please review it and vote to reopen it. I feel that my answer is being targeted by several people unfairly. Thanks for your attention to this matter.

Comment: As Double AA [says](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4292/5323), that answer is not deleted. It has, however, been greyed out because it has been severely downvoted. (I am making no judgement on the quality of the answer; I haven't actually read it. This is just what I see)

Answer (score 4):

The [revision history](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/81599/revisions) of that post shows that it is not deleted now, nor has it ever been deleted.

(Revision histories show deletion and undeletion entries, as seen for example in [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/81566/revisions) of a different post which has been deleted and undeleted.)

Comment: Well, *now* it's been deleted.

Comment: @DonielF ...and undeleted.